# Intermittent loss of power in two circuits without either circuit breaker tripping

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit

The only thing in common with the two circuits is the wires serving them run through the same conduit, but I changed out the wire for one of the circuits and nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement!  Have you tested the voltage in the outlets when the power loss is happening?  Sounds like a loose connection somewhere.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [diy.se]. You're going to have to give us more to go on than this. Please [edit] your post to include a _lot_ more info. Things like: are there switches on these circuits? are there outlets on these circuits? are there lights on these circuits? if so how many/what types of bulbs? what size breakers? what size wiring? what size conduit? As it stands, it's kinda like saying "my car won't start, what's wrong with it?"

Comment: When you changed out the wire for one of the circuits, did you change both the hot and neutral wires, or just the hot? Is there a shared neutral anywhere in this?

Comment: I agree, this question will need a lot more detail to become something we can advise/help with.   OP you can [edit] your question to add detail. Please do.